# How Set Body height in paper when use media print [css]

Tags: css, html, media-queries, css-grid

I don't know how I can set the height of the body when I use `@media print`.

I have a long document. I set every page to have the same header and footer.

**Header**

```
@media print {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Footer**

```
@media print {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

How do I put the body between the header and footer? When I put data in paper the sections {Header body Footer} get overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a grid in your body and place your elements on it:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  display: grid;      
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  min-height: 100vh; // use the full height
}
    header {
  grid-row: 1;
}

main {
  grid-row: 2;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

If you want to only show header and footer during print just hide them for screen by adding this:

```
header, footer {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  header, footer {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

If you want to adapt the height to your paper size instead of the viewport.
You can add the page size like follow (example for A4 paper size):

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    min-height: 297mm;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It isn't work Scroll Bar show in paper when print and papers should to be 4 sheets but It out only one.

Comment: True, that wouldn't work for multiple pages...
I don't think there is any solution for that problem using current HTML 5 and CSS3.

If the sole purpose of the page is printing, you could as a workaround change your html into a table and put the header and footer into <thead> and <tfoot> tags, but this still might be semantically wrong depending on your content.